# if else statement not working according to the way i want in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following code

```
<?php  

foreach($record as $rec) {
    $dates = date('d-M-Y');
    $month_year = date('m-Y');

    if (($rec['dates'] == $dates && $rec['eid'] == $uid)) {
        $today = $rec['amount'];
    }

    if (($rec['dates']  == $month_year  && $rec['eid'] == $uid )) {
        $monthlysale = $rec['amount'];
    }
}

?>
```

I am using foreach loop and my record array has following structure

```
Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 80
        [dates] => 12-Mar-2014
        [eid] => 63
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 80
        [dates] => 12-Mar-2015
        [eid] => 63
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 380
        [dates] => 13-Mar-2015
        [eid] => 63
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 160
        [dates] => 14-Mar-2015
        [eid] => 63
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 80
        [dates] => 03-2014
        [eid] => 63
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [amount] => 620
        [dates] => 03-2015
        [eid] => 63
    )
```

)

I am applying if condition to check if the date which I am getting from array $rec['dates'] is equal to today's date in $dates variable but problem arises here if there is no matching of today's date with date from array then the variable $today becomes undefined as there is no amount corresponding to that date because if there is no date then there is no amount and i don't know how to make condition in foreach loop to make $today=0 if $rec['dates'](date coming from array) is not equal to today's date and second case is that if there is matching of date then if I apply else condition under which I define $today=0 then only else part works.thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define both variables to the default value (zero) before foreach loop.

```
$today = 0;
$monthlysale = 0;

foreach (...) {
    ...
}

// here both variables are defined, you can work with them.
```